# Extracting parameters from SSRS ExecutionLog3 view with a sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to parse the parameters column from the ReportServer ExecutionLog3 view to be able to check the correct execution of reports in a data driven subscription.

This is what I have found so far:

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE (
  c_parameters VARCHAR(1000)
) INSERT @t 
values 
('login=res%5Cel&Album=293&RecordingDate=11%2F03%2F2012%2000%3A00%3A00&ReleaseDate=11%2F12%2F2013%2000%3A00%3A00&ArtistId=404&AlbumName=MidnightDreamscapes'),
('login=res%5Cel&RecordingDate=12%2F05%2F2007%2000%3A00%3A00&ReleaseDate=10%2F15%2F2008%2000%3A00%3A00&Album=580&AlbumName=EtherealHorizons'),
('login=res%5Cel&Album=403&RecordingDate=1%2F01%2F2009%2000%3A00%3A00&ReleaseDate=9%2F18%2F2015%2000%3A00%3A00&SurroundAvailable=1&AlbumName=ElectricOceans'),
('login=res%5Cel&Album=676&RecordingDate=8%2F09%2F2011%2000%3A00%3A00&ReleaseDate=12%2F25%2F2012%2000%3A00%3A00&AlbumName=CosmicEchoes')

SELECT
      cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(Cast(c_Parameters as varchar(900)), '&', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[1]', 'varchar(200)') as param_1
      ,cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(Cast(c_Parameters as varchar(900)), '&', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[2]', 'varchar(200)') as param_2
      ,cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(Cast(c_Parameters as varchar(900)), '&', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[3]', 'varchar(200)') as param_3
      ,cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(Cast(c_Parameters as varchar(900)), '&', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[4]', 'varchar(200)') as param_4
      ,cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(Cast(c_Parameters as varchar(900)), '&', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[5]', 'varchar(200)') as param_5
      ,cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(Cast(c_Parameters as varchar(900)), '&', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[6]', 'varchar(200)') as param_6
      
  FROM @t
```

which give the following results:

```
+─────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────────────────+─────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────+
| param_1         | param_2                                      | param_3                                      | param_4                                    | param_5                     | param_6                        |
+─────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────────────────+─────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────+
| login=res%5Cel  | Album=293                                    | RecordingDate=11%2F03%2F2012%2000%3A00%3A00  | ReleaseDate=11%2F12%2F2013%2000%3A00%3A00  | ArtistId=404                | AlbumName=MidnightDreamscapes  |
| login=res%5Cel  | RecordingDate=12%2F05%2F2007%2000%3A00%3A00  | ReleaseDate=10%2F15%2F2008%2000%3A00%3A00    | Album=580                                  | AlbumName=EtherealHorizons  | NULL                           |
| login=res%5Cel  | Album=403                                    | RecordingDate=1%2F01%2F2009%2000%3A00%3A00   | ReleaseDate=9%2F18%2F2015%2000%3A00%3A00   | AtmosAvailable=1            | AlbumName=ElectricOceans       |
| login=res%5Cel  | Album=676                                    | RecordingDate=8%2F09%2F2011%2000%3A00%3A00   | ReleaseDate=12%2F25%2F2012%2000%3A00%3A00  | AlbumName=CosmicEchoes      | NULL                           |
+─────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────────────+──────────────────────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────────────────+─────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────+
```

I am trying to select the following values in a distinct column:

- for every record:

  - Album, RecordingDate, ReleaseDate, AlbumName, Album
- for the records with a 6th parameter:

  - name of the parameter :

    - ArtistId for first record
    - AtmosAvailable for third record
  - value of the parameter :

    - 404 for fist record
    - 1 for third record

so that it gives the following result:

```
+────────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────+────────+──────────────────────+────────────────────+─────────────+
| RecordingDate                  | ReleaseDate                    | Album  | AlbumName            | ParamName          | ParamValue  |
+────────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────+────────+──────────────────────+────────────────────+─────────────+
| 11%2F03%2F2012%2000%3A00%3A00  | 11%2F12%2F2013%2000%3A00%3A00  | 293    | MidnightDreamscapes  | ArtistId           | 404         |
| 12%2F05%2F2007%2000%3A00%3A00  | 10%2F15%2F2008%2000%3A00%3A00  | 580    | EtherealHorizons     | NULL               | NULL        |
| 1%2F01%2F2009%2000%3A00%3A00   | 9%2F18%2F2015%2000%3A00%3A00   | 403    | ElectricOceans       | SurroundAvailable  | 1           |
| 8%2F09%2F2011%2000%3A00%3A00   | 12%2F25%2F2012%2000%3A00%3A00  | 676    | CosmicEchoes         | NULL               | NULL        |
+────────────────────────────────+────────────────────────────────+────────+──────────────────────+────────────────────+─────────────+
```

Is there some SQL magic that can do this ?

Comment: SQL Server is *terrible* at string manipulation. If you want to parse the parameters of a URL (which is what these are), you'd be better off in a different language in all honesty.

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback, yes that seemed a little bit optimistic to do it in pure SQL.